# Excel graph in AutoCAD automatically update?

Tags: graph, charts, autocad, import-from-excel

Is there a way to have my Excel charts in an AutoCAD layout that automatically updates based on changes made in the spreadsheet?

Right now I'm having to manually copy and paste each chart every time a change is made.

Comment: Look at the second article on [this](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/.services/blog/6a00d83452464869e200d83452baa169e2/search?filter.q=excel) page first. Then look at the others.

Comment: You need to be more clear.  Which API are you using.  Right now we are assuming the AutoCAD .NET API.  If you are talking out-of-box functionality, then this is the wrong forum for this.